# jQuery: delegate adding input fields, multiple times

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is the link : [Demo link](http://articlecon.com/phpdemo/b1/test/wizard)

Click on 'Group' , then click on 'Monetary'. You will see a form with green '+' sign. When this green '+' is clicked, multiple input fields are added, instead of one.

Following is the code on clicking of '+' sign.

Line #    : 178

```
jQuery('#input span.con').delegate('p a[id=add_field]', 'click', function(){ 


var Id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
Id = 1+ parseInt(Id); 

jQuery('#input span.con p span.text_field').append('<span class="text_field" id="'+ Id +'"><input type="text" name="pemails[]" class="text_field" /><a class="edit_field" name="delete" id="'+ Id +'" href=""><img src="'+base_url+'resource/images/fend/delete.png" border="0" /></a></span>');
```

return false;

});

Line #    : 472

```
jQuery('#input span.con').prepend('<p><label for="" class="label">Participent Email:</label><span class="text_field"><span class="text_field">Click here to add the data.<a class="edit_field" name="add_field" id="add_field" href=""><img src="'+base_url+'resource/images/fend/add.png" border="0" /></a></span><span class="text_field" id="1"><input type="text" name="pemails[]" class="text_field" /><a class="edit_field" name="delete" id="1" href=""><img src="'+base_url+'resource/images/fend/delete.png" border="0" /></a></span></span></p>');
    }
```

For js file reference: 
 File name : wizard.js
 Line #    : 178
 Line #    : 472 (It is adding '+' sign through javascript)

Can some one guide me where Iam doing wrong and how it can be rectified.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As you've asked **30** previous questions, with respect, by now you really should be formatting code correctly. Please refer to the handy **How to Format** box to the right of the Ask a Question box, and to [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area. There's a preview area under the Ask a Question area for seeing what the result will look like.

Comment: Separately (as most of us will not follow the link): I'm guessing that when you click the link, the fields are not getting added. Is that what you're seeing? Are you seeing anything happen? Do you see anything in a debugger?

Comment: use easy way to do this directly clone that control and add

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder: I will surely consider your advice about formatting questions.  2- Fields are added but multiple times. Like on first click, 2 fields would be added, on 2nd click four new input fields would be added and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have repeated ids, never. That may be causing you problems.

You are giving the same ids (Id var) to the span and the a in this line (and they are numerical , shouldn't be!)

```
jQuery('#input span.con p span.text_field').append('<span ... id="'+ Id +'">...<a ... id="'+ Id +'" ...>...</a></span>');
```

My advise is to use ids like the following:

```
var aId = "a"+Id;
var spanId = "span"+Id;
```

So you'd have:

```
jQuery('#input span.con p span.text_field').append('<span ... id="'+ spanId +'">...<a ... id="'+ aId +'" ...>...</a></span>');
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: It is still adding input boxes multiple times.